# App crashes when loading multiple png images

Tags: android, caching, android-activity, delete-file, temp

I have a few layouts. Each one has a PNG image fullscreen.
Any one activity open fine. But to open the other one I have to re-start the app.
App FORCE CLOSES when opening the other activity by going back a screen and choosing the button for other activity.

Is there a way to delete TEMP or cache as soon as we press the back button OR as soon as we chose another activity

Comment: If you look at the [Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) you can set & remove your PNG image in `Activity#onStart()` and `Activity#onStop()`.

Comment: "But to open the other one I have to re-start the app." - is it the part of your task? Where is the question itself? I don't see a single question mark. The last sentence coud be a question, but which cache do you want to delete? What Temp? File? Storage? How do you choose another activity? From WHAT activity? Please, be MUCH more concrete. Better write down your code here.

Answer (score 0):

- `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` will give you SDcard path. There you can erase something from TEMP storage. You meant this?